# Magento 2 - product is showing via url, but it isn't appearing in the frontend

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento-2.1.8, visibility

I'm having a problem with **Magento 2**, I've created a configurable product like how I do it every time. However, some **products** aren't showing in the **frontend** of the categories, If I try opening it up the URL, I'm able to see the product, but it just won't list in the categories I added to.

Any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE, I would definitely look into clearing caches & be sure indexes are updating properly.

Comment: Are you talking about the particular configurable product is not showing in the frontend or about it's simple product is not showing?

Comment: 'Hi @B00MER, thanks for the reply, yes I have tried clearing all the caches and reindexed. Still couldn't get it showing. Products that I've added later actually shows.

Comment: @ABHISHEKTRIPATHI yes - that is right, the configuration has all been checked, I couldn't workout what is the issue. The visibility has been set to Catalog: Search". Quantity, prices, categories has been set.

Comment: If talking about the configurable product it can be seen on the frontend in its particular category but if talking about its configuration (simple products (product which are sub-products of our configurable product)) they will not be seen on the front end if you didn't enabled them to be seen on the frontend

Comment: If you have given that permission then see it can be a n indexer or cache issue so just reindex your products & clear the cache to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that this product is set to "Visibility: Catalog, Search", make sure that magento is reindexed and after reindex clear the cache.